# Jetty User-Defined Configuration

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

In my application, I have certain parameters (Strings) that I would like to change from server to server.

For example, one of those parameters is a yes/no value that tells if the server is a production environment. Another is the file-path of a given resource in the specific machine where the application is running. Etc.

I would like to keep these values in a separate configuration file (plain text, xml, JSON, or another simple format), in the directory structure of my Jetty web-server.

Is there a way of accomplishing this, that allows simple retrieval of the String values by key, from within my servlets, without having to install additional software, or to configure complicated Jetty options? I really would like to avoid complications for just two or three values that I need to retrieve.

EDIT:
I am using servlets directly, without any additional web framework, no Spring, etc. The software is coded in Scala.

JNDI would probably do what I need, but I would like something simpler to set up.

I guess I am looking for something like ServletConfig, but at the server level, not the web-app level.

Comment: Why don't you just define environment variables with these values at each server?

Comment: Some servers are Windows, others Linux; I develop on OS X. I wanted something consistent across all the environments, and easy to edit in just one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example.

In your jetty-distribution directory, you have a `/resources/` directory (which is included by default at the server level classloader via the `OPTIONS` configuration found in the `/start.ini` file)

If you create `/resources/myconfig.properties` (for example) with the following content:

```
food=fruit
fruit.color=yellow
fruit.name=banana
```

Then you can have a Servlet load it on init() like this:

```
public class LoadResourceServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private Properties props;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        super.init(config);

        props = new Properties();
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/myconfig.properties");
        if (url != null)
        {
            try (InputStream stream = url.openStream())
            {
                props.load(stream);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        try (PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter())
        {
            writer.printf("food = %s%n",props.getProperty("food"));
            writer.printf("fruit.color = %s%n",props.getProperty("fruit.color"));
            writer.printf("fruit.name = %s%n",props.getProperty("fruit.name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting! Could I use getClass().getResource() in other parts of my code (like when some singleton objects get created), or is it tied to the `/resources` file only at the servlet `init()`?

Comment: .getClass().getResource() is a basic ClassLoader concept.  it just loads from whatever is in the classloader.  In the case of /resources/ directory, i chose that as its already present as a directory classloader reference courtesy of the OPTIONS line in the start.ini.  To see what's in the server classpath/classloader use this command line in the distribution `java -jar start.jar --version`.

Comment: FYI, I chose to use a properties file as its already baked into java and made the example work without extra 3rd party libraries.  You can use any config file format you want, just load it from the URL or InputStream.  In the above example, if the `url` is null, that means it couldn't find the configuration file. (guess i could have thrown an error there)